# Asana Tasks Not Showing Created_At Date?

Tags: asana-api, asa

I'm using the asana gem and trying to get all created_at dates for all tasks in all my projects.  I can get names and ids to show, but not other fields.  For example, created_at returns a blank when printed to the screen.  It would seem like every task should have a created_at date.

Code is below:

```js
client.workspaces.find_all.each do |workspace|
   puts "\t* #{workspace.name} - projects:"
   client.projects.find_by_workspace(workspace: workspace.id, per_page: 20).each do |projects|
    puts "\t\t*- #{projects.name} - tasks"
     projects.tasks.find_all.each do |task| 
        puts "\t\t\t*- #{task.name}"
        puts "\t\t\t*- #{task.id}"
        puts "\t\t\t*- #{task.assignee}"
        puts "\t\t\t*- #{task.due_on}"
        puts "\t\t\t*- #{task.created_at}"
        puts "\t\t\t*- #{task.completed_at}"
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to specify options on fields you want to see.
By default, when we expand a list we only show you the name and id. You can do this with:

projects.tasks.find_all(options: { fields: ["created_at", ...] }).each...

See https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options for more information.